# Silverlight Initialise Error 2110 Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, internet-explorer

We develop a Silverlight application, the latest version of which we have just deployed to our clients.

The problem is that some of our clients are getting errors when they attempt to access the application in Internet Explorer. The application loads fine in Google Chrome.

The error initially manifested itself as showing the Silverlight loading animation, getting to 100% and disappearing leaving a white page or simply sticking at 100%.

Having enabled JavaScript debugging, an error dialog appears informing the user of the following:

```
Line: 62
Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application
Code: 2110   
Category: InitializeError      
Message: 2110 An error has occurred.
```

We cannot get any further than this. Can anyone shed any light on this issue?

Thanks very much,

Martyn.

Comment: Have you checked that Chrome is not caching a previous working version? Chrome loves to cache our Silverlight application where as IE picks up the latest version. Try disabling the Cache using the Chrome F12 Tools

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the problem is IE specific, Chrome is working fine, as is IE for most clients, just a couple with the issue.

Answer (score 10):

I am very late, but since I could not find the answer that eventually solve the issue for me I am posting here for others :

In my case, the answer was to set back the compilation platform to "any CPU" I got the 2110 error in x86 and it loaded properly using "any CPU".

Answer (score 4):

In my experience this is almost always a problem with dependencies.

To prove that it is, create a new Silverlight project and include all the references you have in your existing project and see if you get a white screen of death.

If you do then try removing references from your test SL project one at a time until you get something that works.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

There are many reasons that cause this error. It may be from your code or IE itself. Could you ask the users do things such as:

1. Try to disable IE9 compatibility view. (Press F12)
2. Clear IE cache then close and re-open it before you go to the website.

If none of them works, you should check xaml code or attach the Silverlight process to the debugger and debug the code.

Comment: I have also tried these things to no avail. I also cannot debug the error as I cannot reproduce it, it is only happening for a couple of our users, most are fine. This makes me think it is not an error in our code...

Comment: I suggest you warp the code that you think it causes the error by `try ... catch` then print its stack trace out.

Comment: After wasting a whole day, finally your solution 
"Clear IE cache then close and re-open it before you go to the website."
resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but in Firefox x64, when I have in Silverlight csproj:

```
<Reference Include="mscorlib">
    <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

When I changed it to:

```
<Reference Include="mscorlib" />
```

everything goes well.